# Workflow reminder based on due date including change of due date

Tags: alert, reminder

I want to create a WF reminder based on "due date - 3 days".

I have achieved my goal with the following;

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't support change of due data. Tried a workaround with calculated columns - but in this example, I simply don't receive emails.

[image]

What should I adjust? I tried to read other plots (where I found the above logic) but now I am lost. I have set both WF to set up automatically and when items change.

Answer (score 1):

I may have to write in a parallel stage with the "Wait for change" action for Due date and the "Pause until" action until due date. Afterwards, you can determine if the change was made and go back to Stage 1 and wait again, or move onto the next stage.

Comment: hello, google about what you wrote, and isnt that so, if wait for change is used, that due date needs equal to certain value?

Comment: See this: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/07/05/run-only-one-not-all-of-parallel-actions-with-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/